# Why angular is undefined in here

Tags: angularjs

Since i'm new to programming world i started with angularjs code.
I would like to know why this error keeps occuring . Every time i provide angular module name it shows angular is undefined.

[image]

```js
// Weather app module creation

var weather = angular.module('weather', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])

// config

weather.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider

    .when('./', {
      templateUrl: 'home.htm',
      controller: 'homeC'
    })
    .when('/forecast', {
      templateUrl: 'fore.html',
      controller: 'foreC'
    })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="weather">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Weather</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href=".\bootstrap-4.0.0-dist\css\bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Weather</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <div ng-view>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Share your code, not image. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: show your full error, it might be a syntax error. I can't imagine your bootstrap css has a correct link

Answer (score 1):

Your script is loaded before angular library.
This one should work:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="weather">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Weather</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href=".\bootstrap-4.0.0-dist\css\bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Weather</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <div ng-view>

    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  var weather = angular.module('weather', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])

// config

weather.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider

    .when('./', {
      templateUrl: 'home.htm',
      controller: 'homeC'
    })
    .when('/forecast', {
      templateUrl: 'fore.html',
      controller: 'foreC'
    })
})
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```